# Which files should I be looking at to do a total conversion mod using the Source Engine?

Tags: modding

I just installed Source SDK. Made a multiplayer mod from a template using Source Engine 2007. I'm currently using VS2008.

I was wondering which folder I should work in. For example weapons, which files I should change?

Is it "\src\game\server\hl2\weapon_crowbar.cpp"
or "\src\game\shared\hl2mp\weapon_crowbar.cpp"
or "\src\game\shared\sdk\weapon_crowbar.cpp"

Also, I've seen the various help on the wiki, if I want to change bullets for example, saying I should change the scripts in the mod folder in Steam. Is that necessary? Shouldn't I make changes from the source mod folder to things like that and recompile?

I'm aiming for a total conversion mod rather than just a mini-mod in case that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the project you're using.

- Game_Episodic_2005.sln: use /hl2/ crowbar (from HL2/Episodes).
- Game_HL2MP_2005.sln: use /hl2mp/ crowbar (from HL2: Deathmatch, probably optimized for multiplayer).
- Game_Scratch_2005.sln: use /sdk/ crowbar (I think it's an example weapon here).

For total conversions, use Game_Scratch_2005, but it has several errors when compiling, Game_Episodic_2005 compiles without any errors on Release configuration, but contains HL2 content. It is HIGHLY NOT recommended to compile without HL2_DLL (HL2_CLIENT_DLL) parameter while using Game_Episodic_2005 as errors may occur.

Comment: I followed the help on the source page and fixed the various problems with the compilation. Now I finally know what I should tinker with however! Thank you for the detailed response. :)